# Ansible Dynamic Inventory

Tags: ansible

I'm running a playbook which houses multiple roles targets multiple hosts

The goal is to deploy a VM and use it's IP to deploy an app.

My playbook, has two roles, using "build_vm" role I'm able to display IP address via debug, yet when passing ipaddr variable to second role, Ansible complains that the variable is not defined

```
- hosts: linux
  become: true

  roles:
  - build_vm

    - tasks:
       - debug: msg="{{ ipaddr }}"      

- hosts: "{{ ipaddr }}"
  roles:
  - deploy_app
```

I have used set_fact with and ran into same issue, I wonder what I should be using here? dynamic inventory? I have searched sparse docs online and I'm unable to find an intuitive example to follow.

Comment: Please read about [add_host](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/add_host_module.html) module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to using `add_host`. In this example, I am adding the new host to a group and using it in a later play.

```
- hosts: linux
  become: true

  roles:
  - build_vm

    - tasks:
       - debug: msg="{{ ipaddr }}"  
       - name: Add ipaddr to host inventory
         add_host: name="{{ ipaddr }}" group=NewHostGroup    

- hosts: NewHostGroup
  roles:
  - deploy_app
```